# Spring MVC xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, config, thymeleaf

I am trying to configure Spring MVC in xml because I do not want (yet) use config classes.

I think there is something missing beacuse I does not work if I remove the following config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {

}
```

Here is my webmv-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean           class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="es.webtools.eencuesta.api.config.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>


<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="**" />
</bean>
```

- Component scan is in applicationContext.xml file:

Versions:
Spring: 3.2.0.RELEASE
Spring MVC: 3.2.0.RELEASE
Thymeleaf: 2.1.4

Does anyone knows what xml entry am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but you can try to tell Spring MVC servlet where is the configuration file.
In your servlet configuration in you web.xml add a init param:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/webmv-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: Actually, the file webmvc-servlet.xml is being processed (tymeleaf is working), is just enabling MVC that does not work. The solution you proposed does not makes configuration file unnecessary, but thanks anyway.

Comment: So the problem is in webmvc-servlet.xml file.  In my projects i excplicity put Spring MVC controllers component scan (independent for the one i put on services.xml for services layer):    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project.controller" />

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to use a XML configuration for your Spring MVC project,
then you can use a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping Spring class to map your URL with the controller. Below is a snippet:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
       <!-- http://localhost:8080/(Project_Name)/(URL_Mapping_as_below eg: index , wel and hello in the below example)  is the URL context -->
        <props>
           <prop key="/index.html">WelcomeController</prop>
           <prop key="/wel.html">WelcomeController</prop>
           <prop key="/hello.html">WelcomeController</prop>
         </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="WelcomeController" class="com.kl.controllers.WelcomeController" />
```

Here i have mapped 3 URL's to a single Controller, and i don't need to use a config class or annotations to make this work.

I have a working project (basically the whole project of the snippet i have attached above). {https://youtu.be/Vm4XFrWjDhE} The source code is in the video's description.

Cheers ..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Links are not generally acceptable as an answer by themselves, please include enough information in your answer to be useful without the link (although you may keep it there for extra clarification)

Comment: @CollinD Thanks. I have added more information along with the link for viewers reference.

Comment: @Shel Thanks. I have added more information along with the link for viewers reference.

Answer (score 1):

the tag < mvc:annotation-driven> was introduced in [spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver) so that the default handlers and converters are automatically available to your mvc application, [ check section 17.16.1 Enabling the MVC Java Config or the MVC XML Namespace in the link] .So if you really want to do a web app in spring without annotation here are the choices .

1. Since its a learning exercise , revert to a version of spring lower than 3 and then manually declare the dispatcherservlet and other beans you want. Once you are done learning move on to spring 3.

or

2.Its not that  is taking away great power from you ,all its doing is taking further the DI/IoC style spring popularized . Since the magic will be done by respective classes in MVC framework (say a json converter),it doesn't really affect your learning ,whether you declare their init and injection manually or otherwise , unless ofcourse someone is coming from pure j2ee to spring :)
Njy.

Comment: It is indeed a legacy app upgraded to Spring 3. It works fine by using XML + config class. The thing is that it is annoying not being able to configure it as shown in sping doc.

Comment: btw: converter with custom object mapper is needed also: old hibernate version :(

Comment: can you not follow spring 2 document  or book and do the migration? Spring doesn't really restrict you in using bean because its manually declared not via annotation-driven tag.

Comment: Those are the steps I am going to follow next. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Vote the answer or comment if u found them useful☺

Comment: I can not: not enogh reputation :(